# Monitoring Connectivity on ZigBee

Tags: electrical-engineering, control-engineering, telecommunication, wireless-communication, networking

I am trying to figure out some ways in which a ZigBee network can be monitored. As is the case in any network, here we have a central coordinator and several slaves joined, however, there seems to be a tendency for the established links to break during operation.

I'm not entirely sure why this happens, but I was wondering whether there is a means in ZigBee to monitor the 'strength' of connection. Repeatedly pinging is of course, one way to do so, but are there any other, possibly less demanding options?